# Learning Rate in Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network

I am new in field of neural networks and recently I came to know that very slow learning rate affects accuracy negatively. I understand that very low learning rate will make it inefficient but how accuracy is affected by low learning rate?

Answer (score 0):

when learning rate is too large, it can cause the model to converge too quickly to a solution that is not optimal, think it as overshooting. On the contrary, when learning rate is too small, it can make the model get stuck (due to tiny steps taken to converge) to a local minimum which is not the optimal solution again.
Therefore accuracy is affected and the goal is to find the best learning rate for the that model.